# Sum of integer variables bash script

Tags: bash, shell

How can I do the sum of integers with bash script I read some variables with a for and I need to do the sum.

I have written the code like this:

```
Read N 
Sum=0
for ((i=1;i<=N;i++))
do
   read number 
   sum=sum+number
done
echo $sum
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and format the code?

Comment: I am browsing from mobile I dont know how to do that

Comment: Very little needs to change. `sum=$(( sum + number ))` -- after changing your `Read N` and `Sum=0` to `read N` and `sum=0`.

Answer (score 5):

Use the arithmetic command `((...))`:

```
#! /bin/bash
read n
sum=0
for ((i=1; i<=n; i++)) ; do
   read number 
   ((sum+=number))
done
echo $sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter number:"
read N
re='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ ${N} =~ ${re} ]]
then
    echo "Error. It's not a number"
    exit 1
fi
Sum=0
for ((i=1;i<=N;i++))
do
sum=$((${sum} + ${i}))
done
echo "${sum}"
```

Comment: This is quite a lot of complexity to add functionality the OP didn't ask for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not a straight bash solution, but you can also use `seq` and `datamash` (https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
#!/bin/bash

read N
seq 1 $N | datamash sum 1
```

It is really simple (and it has its limitations), but it works. You can use other options on `seq` for increments different than 1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to declare a variable as an integer with `declare -i`. Any assignment to that variable is then evaluated as an arithmetic expression:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i sum=0                           
read -p "Enter n: " n

for ((i=1; i<=n; i++)) ; do
   read -p "Enter number #$i: " number
   sum+=number #sum=sum+number would also work
done

echo "Sum: $sum"
```

See [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) for more information. Using arithmetic command `((...))` is preferred, see [choroba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48285310/6176817).

---

```
$ declare -i var1=1
$ var2=1

$ var1+=5
$ echo "$var1"
6

$ var2+=5
$ echo "$var2"
15
```

This can be a tad confusing as `+=` behaves differently depending on the variable's attributes. It's therefore better to explicitly use `((...))` for arithmetic operations.